# Substrings in Swift

Tags: swift, substring

I'm having a problem with understand how I can work with substrings in Swift. Basically, I'm getting a JSON value that has a string with the following format:

```
<a href="#">Something</a>
```

I'm trying to get rid of the HTML anchor tag with Swift so I'm left with `Something`. My thought was to find the index of every `<` and `>` in the string so then I could just do a substringWithRange and advance up to the right index.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to find the index. I've read that Swift doesn't support the index (unless you extend it.)

I don't want to add CPU cycles unnecessarily. So my question is, how do I find the indexes in a way that is not inefficient? Or, is there a better way of filtering out the tags?

**Edit:** Converted Andrew's first code sample to a function:

```
func formatTwitterSource(rawStr: String) -> String {
    let unParsedString = rawStr
    var midParseString = ""
    var parsedString = ""

    if let firstEndIndex = find(unParsedString, ">") {
        midParseString = unParsedString[Range<String.Index>(start: firstEndIndex.successor(), end: unParsedString.endIndex)]
        if let secondStartIndex = find(midParseString, "<") {
            parsedString = midParseString[Range<String.Index>(start: midParseString.startIndex, end: secondStartIndex)]
        }
    }          
    return parsedString
}
```

Nothing too complicated. It takes in a String that has the tags in it. Then it uses Andrew's magic to parse everything out. I renamed the variables and made them clearer so you can see which variable does what in the process. Then in the end, it returns the parsed string.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661722/removing-everything-between-a-certain-set-of-characters-with-swift/27662573#27662573

Comment: Beware that none of those answers can convert HTML Entities like line breaks <br> to \n and/or special HTML Entities like &pound; &copy; &nbsp, etc...

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus You're right. But to be fair, I only asked about <a>. I have to ask though, in your answer in the other thread, does that parse for everything?

Comment: Yes but the result is a regular String.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Nice! I'll keep that bookmarked next time I have to parse out HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, but it isn't pretty really. Obviously you would want to factor this into a function and possibly allow for various start/end tokens.

```
let testText = "<a href=\"#\">Something</a>"
if let firstEndIndex = find(testText, ">") {
    let testText2 = testText[Range<String.Index>(start: firstEndIndex.successor(), end: testText.endIndex)]
    if let secondStartIndex = find(testText2, "<") {
        let testText3 = testText2[Range<String.Index>(start: testText2.startIndex, end: secondStartIndex)]
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

Working on this a little further and came up with something a little more idiomatic?

```
let startSplits = split(testText, { $0 == "<" })
let strippedValues = map(startSplits) { (s) -> String? in
    if let endIndex = find(s, ">") {
        return s[Range<String.Index>(start: endIndex.successor(), end: s.endIndex)]
    }
    return nil
}
let strings = map(filter(strippedValues, { $0 != "" })) { $0! }
```

It uses a little more functional style there at the end. Not sure I much enjoy the Swift style of map/filter compared to Haskell. But anyhow, the one potentially dangerous part is that forced unwrapping in the final `map`. If you can live with a result of `[String?]` then it isn't necessary.

Comment: Good deal. Again, you will probably need to take that basic shell and flesh it out a little more to be a little more general, but it should be a solid starting point.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently rewriting it as a function and adding in the necessary parameters and return types. Also adding a little more to make it a little more catch all, but the foundation was all I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @ShaanSingh maybe check out the new version I posted. It is a little more flexible but would still need to be converted to taking the splitting tokens in as parameters.

Comment: Oh god that's nice! I edited my question to show you how I set up the function for the old version. This one is a little nicer though. Definitely more flexible.

Comment: I'll start setting this one up.

Comment: Well that was easy. Just like the one in the question. Takes in a rawStr and returns [String].

Comment: This answer totally ignores HTML Entities like <br> &pound; &copy; &nbsp, et

Comment: That is true - it is not a complete replacement for the UIKit extensions on NSAttributedString, but it does address the question specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question has been already answered, I am adding solution based on regex.

```
let pattern = "<.*>(.*)<.*>"
let src = "<a href=\"#\">Something</a>"
var error: NSError? = nil

var regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .DotMatchesLineSeparators, error: &error)

if let regex = regex {
    var result = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(src, options: nil, range: NSRange(location:0,
    length:countElements(src)), withTemplate: "$1")
    println(result)
}
```