# NSAttributedString strange error in iPhone and not iPad

Tags: ios, swift

I am running below code & error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error happens only in iPhone & not in iPad running same iOS 8.1.2. I tried replacing nil of `documentAttributes` to below &tempDictionary, but that won't compile.

Any help please?

```
    var error: NSError?
    var tempDictionary: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDictionary?> = nil

    var title = "Message &#8211; Test"

    var attrStr = NSAttributedString(
        data: title.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil,
        error: &error)

    if let actualError = error {
        println("An Error Occurred: \(actualError)")
    }

    textLabel!.attributedText = attrStr
```

The error is obviously not clear in iPhone. I can see this in the stack.

```
 @!objc ext.UIKit.ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString.init
 (ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString.Type)(data : ObjectiveC.NSData, options
 : Swift.Optional<Swift.Dictionary<ObjectiveC.NSObject,
 Swift.AnyObject>>, documentAttributes :
 Swift.AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.NSDictionary>>,
 error :
 Swift.AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.NSError>>)
 -> Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString> at MasterViewController.swift
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661722/removing-everything-between-a-certain-set-of-characters-with-swift/27662573#27662573

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Thanks for the quick reply. The function you pointed has exact code which I have. So same result. I am adding some content from stack trace. Not sure if that makes sense.