# A swift wrapper around libxml for parsing HTML

Tags: html, xcode, parsing, swift, ios8

I'm getting an odd error message saying "Extra argument 'endocing' in call", but it's in the method, so it's not an extra argument? Why is this happening and how can I resolve this? The error message appears when declaring the variable "parser" as you can see. Thanks!

```
if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string:"http://www.mobladet.se") {

            if let htmlString = String(contentsOfURL: checkedUrl, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {

                // Parsing HTML

                let opt = CInt(HTML_PARSE_NOERROR.value | HTML_PARSE_RECOVER.value)

                var err : NSError?

                var parser = HTMLParser(html: htmlString, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, option: opt, error: &err)

                var bodyNode = parser.body

                // Create an array of the part of HTML you need

                if let inputNodes = bodyNode?.findChildTags("h4") {

                    for node in inputNodes {

                        let result = html2String(node.rawContents)

                        println(result)

                    }
                }

            } else {

                println("Could not load HTML Content")
            }
        }
```

Comment: html should be HTML code to be parsed not a NSURL

Comment: You need to fetch your NSURL content and them parse it

Comment: Yes, I follow you now, sorry for being so stupid =( Could you please give me a short example of I should do that? Many thanks!

Comment: @ look at my posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html should be HTML code to be parsed not a NSURL. You need to use String( contentsOfURL:) to extract its contents and them parse it

```
if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string:"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751228/a-swift-wrapper-around-libxml-for-parsing-html"){
    if let htmlString = String(contentsOfURL: checkedUrl, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {

        println(htmlString)
    } else {
        println("could not load html string from the url")
    }
} else {
    println("invalid url")
}
```

Comment: String returns an optional string you should safely unwrap your url and your string just in case one of them returns nil

Comment: Thanks! It works now =) Sorry for asking again, but I'm new to this parsing thing =) How could I get the title of this post: <h4 class="widget-title">Senaste nyheterna</h4><ul><li><a href="http://mellanosternbladet.se/seyyed-ali-khameneis-brev-till-unga-i-vast/">"Seyyed Ali Khameneis brev till unga i väst"</a><span class="post-date">4 februari, 2015</span></li>

Comment: I have already answered that many times I will find the answer if it solves the problem just up vote it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661722/removing-everything-between-a-certain-set-of-characters-with-swift/27662573#27662573

Comment: I have edited above linked answer and included the NSAttributedString extension also

Comment: Awesome! I think I got it now, just the way I want it! Can I give you a Golden Star?

Comment: @Erik Thanks You can upvote all my answers that you may find useful (300+ answers) only Swift  :)

Comment: I will do that! But I noticed something in the logs, its giving me h4 titles like I wanted but it gives me one per second or something, its not fast? Something is not right? I will update my code above =)

Comment: @Erik Lydecker updating the Question isn't a good idea. Feel free to open a new question describing your new issue :). As you know future readers may also benefit from your first question. You can always roll back your edits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71830/discussion-between-erik-lydecker-and-leonardo-savio-dabus).